# YouTube account suspended, what now?

Tags: youtube, copyright

My YouTube account has been suspended for the video I created. And I still doubt I have broken any law.

Here is the email I got after filling an error request. I do not understand how to work on the text I have emboldened:

> Thanks for your email. Your "yadishansar" account has been suspended
>   due to repeated or severe violations of our Terms of Use and claims of
>   copyright infringement. Suspended accounts cannot be reinstated.
>   Federal law requires that we terminate accounts when there are
>   repeated claims of copyright infringement. Because you have had other
>   videos rejected in the past, we are unable to reinstate your account.
>   Users with suspended or terminated accounts are prohibited from
>   creating new accounts or accessing YouTube’s community. **In order for
>   your account to be reinstated, you will need to resolve at least one
>   of the following video removals.**
>
> The following videos have been removed from your account:
>
> Penalty 1: "How to Download Facebook Video - without any plugin or
>   software (DIY Tutorial)" formerly at
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9WTGpe_Sbs Removed for violating our
>   Terms of Use on 11/16/2012. Please see http://www.youtube.com/t/terms
>   and http://www.youtube.com/t/community_guidelines
>
> To learn more about copyright, please visit YouTube’s Copyright Center
>   at: http://www.youtube.com/t/copyright_education
>
> To learn more about the consequences of alleged infringement, please
>   visit: http://www.youtube.com/t/copyright_strike
>
> If you are sure a content owner has misidentified your content as
>   infringing, learn more at: http://www.youtube.com/t/copyright_counter
>
> PLEASE NOTE this is an automated response.  Any replies to this
>   message will not be reviewed.
>
> Regards,
>
> The YouTube Team

What to do now? Can I reinstate my YouTube account, or at least create a new account from the same email address?

Comment: Is that really the only video that they removed?

Comment: I uploaded some 2 or 3 copyright videos in past and deleted them myself when I got notification. This video was only telling how to find direct link of .mp4 video in source code of facebook video page.

Comment: Related Youtube official help article: [Changes to account standing | Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797387?hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now after a whole year, I appealed once again to reinstate my account (although I don't remember what I actually did, but I did something) and received following email from YouTube.

> Hi there,
>
> Thank you for your email.
>
> We have re-reviewed the circumstances of your suspension and have
>   concluded it is appropriate to reinstate your account. This means your
>   account is once again active and operational.
>
> If you have forgotten your password, please visit this link to reset
>   it: http://www.youtube.com/account_recovery
>
> Sincerely,
>
> The YouTube Team

Finally: Account reinstated!